# Can we access s3 input path from AWS data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to find out how to access input s3 path in aws data pipeline. If we are dealing with shellcommandactivity and there is an input data node with a path to some s3 location (e.g. s3://mybucket/myfile), how can we access it within the script? I am using python boto to implement shell command activity. I can connect to s3 location and iterate through all the buckets (and files underneath) using something like this :

bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
rs = bucket.list()
for r in rs :
   ...

But can we directly access the s3 input path using boto? Can we do something like this ?

mykey = conn.get_key('s3://mybucket/myfile')

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

unless I missed something just do:

```
bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
my_key = bucket.get_key('myfile')
```